# Mass Dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am wondering if anyone can give some safe guidelines on the maximum level of dom manipulation you can do with jquery without freezing the browser.

Also the best methods for mass DOM manipulation.

Basically at any one time I could be dealing with lists of up to 40k `li`'s

All I am really doing is showing one, hiding the other.

So here are my questions

- **How many li's could I theoretically manipulate at a time without crashing the browser?**

  **How should I work with the li's?**

  - Manipulate as a single object (ul level)
  - Loop over each li in the first list removing them, then loop inserting each new li.
  - Loop over chunks of li's (if so how big 10, 100, 1000, 10000 at a time?)

  **How should I fetch the data? (its in json format)**

  - Grab the data for the entire list (40k li's worth) in one ajax call.
  - Insert the data for every list at page creation(could be upwards of 20 lists = 800,000 li's
  - Do several ajax calls to fetch the data (if so how big 10, 100, 1000, 10000 at a time?)

Comment: Hmm. 40k `li` s? That is a lot. Who is going to ever look at them all? Have you considered lazy loading or pagination?

Comment: The answer will be wildly different for each different browser implementation. I think the answer to this question will come from the tests you perform yourself, rather than any answer provided here.

Comment: As @Pekka says, why not paginate? A DOM that big will piss off your users.

Comment: us a virtual machine or throttle your RAM to 1G for testing purposes. I would suggest integrating a timer into your looping functions so that when the timer exceeds a certain duration you set a brief timeout before continuing to iterate. Ideally it would give the browser a moment to catch its breath before continuing on long processes.

Comment: ok guys, I will try pagination, the next question that comes to mind is, Say I load up a group, and i view 5 pages, Should I store those pages (as variables) anywhere so I can quickly load them up again, or fetch them each time. I am thinking about memory usage ect.

Comment: @Hailwood totally depends on what you use on server side.

Comment: @Pekka if you mean technology php +mysql, no caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to be manipulating that many then you should probably adopt something like http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/async-queue/

As the answer for how many you should be working with at a time, you could build in a calibration which looks at how quickly the last set completed and work with more / less accordingly. This could get you something that works in everything from desktop chrome to mobile IE.

The same goes for the ajax calls, make it able to ramp up according to the net speed.

Answer (score 1):

As a warning: this is extremely dependent on your computer performance. Frankly - anything approaching 100 elements in a DOM manipulation starts getting a little silly and expensive. That said:

1) Depends on your system, my older system tops at about 30 and my newer one can get up to 120 before I break things.

2) Work with them on as large a level as possible. Manipulating a ul with a bunch of li's in it is much faster than manipulating a bunch of li's. Use jQuery and store the object in a variable (so you're not querying the DOM each time it's used) to enhance performance.

3) Initially load the first data the user will see, then fetch it in similarly sized batches. If you can only see 20 li elements at a time there is no reason loading any more than that plus a little buffer area (30?).